# Passing encoded URL query param using RestClient in Ruby giving incorrect result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client, net-http

I am trying to access a private API endpoint that accepts a phone number, including the country code, in the URL query parameters. Because the phone number has to include the "+", the phone number has to be encoded (i.e. the '+' becomes '%2B')

When I call this:
`RestClient.get("mytestserver.com/get_info?phone=%2B11231231234")` in ruby, i get back an invalid response, that indicates its hitting the server, but the value isn't being read correctly.

The same call in the browser, works.

I was able to get it to work using the Net::HTTP class, by doing the following:

```
uri = URI("http://mytestserver.com/get_info")
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({phone: "+11231231234"})
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

But I wanted to see if there was a way to do it via RestClient?

Comment: _i get back an invalid response, that indicates its hitting the server, but the value isn't being read correctly._ How do you know this? Please provide logs and an explanation for why you believe it is the + symbol that is causing the issue.

Comment: Could you check server logs and provide details about how server is receiving request?

Answer (score 0):

It works like this.

```
phone = CGI.escape('+11231231234')
RestClient.get("localhost:3000/test?phone=#{phone}")
```

logs on server:

```
Started GET "/test?phone=%2B11231231234" for ::1 at 2020-09-25 11:13:13 +0100
Processing by TestersController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"phone"=>"+11231231234"}
  Rendering testers/index.html.erb within layouts/application
```